# Rails print (dump) variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, inspect, puts

When debugging, I usually use `puts some_variable.inspect` to print (dump) the variable. However, I am tired of typing `puts ...inspect` every time. Is there a better way to print variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Kernel.html#method-i-p

`p variable` is a shortcut for `puts variable.inspect`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) debugger

```
 #Gemfile
  gem 'pry-rails'

  @data = {content: 'important'}
  #instead of puts @data.inspec
  binding.pry
```

Run the code it will hold on the line, where binding.pry was called and start a pry terminal session.

```
  pry(main)> @data
  => {:content=>"important"}
   pry(main)> cd @data
   pry(#<Hash>):1> ls -m
  Enumerable#methods:
    all?            count       each_cons         entries     flat_map  map     minmax     reduce        take
    any?            cycle       each_entry        find        grep      max     minmax_by  reverse_each  take_while
    chunk           detect      each_slice        find_all    group_by  max_by  none?      slice_before  zip
    collect         drop        each_with_index   find_index  inject    min     one?       sort
    collect_concat  drop_while  each_with_object  first       lazy      min_by  partition  sort_by
```

Comment: Must check http://confreaks.com/videos/2864-rubyconf2013-repl-driven-development-with-pry for more details on how to debug using pry